# Is this possible to keep polling http after the user inactive the iOS application?

Tags: ios, long-polling, polling

I got a programme, it requires polling result from the HTTP server, but the HTTP Server won't connect to Apple push notification server. So, is this possible to keep polling after the user click the home bottom? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 Apple introduced the ability for apps to refresh their data when the connection is started up by another app. You need to implement [application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a)